# mysqldump: ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 222: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating mysqldump backup and then try to import through `mysql < file.dmp` but amazing show below mention error:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 222: Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Comment: The question is unclear. One needs to post the script so we understand the sequence of command that happen and why the FK creation failed. The timing is important. The data in place at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the FK relationship on "mysqldump" or backup the whole database and import.

Comment: but i want foreign keys without this table useless.

Comment: Are you able to remove the FK relationship, import and then reapply the FK relationship?